# PowerShell workflow hello world no output

Tags: powershell, output, workflow

```
workflow helloworld {

"Hello World"

}
```

very simple.  saved to file helloworld.ps1
executed with:

```
.\helloworld.ps1
```

I get no output,  just returns silently.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You only *define* your workflow and not calling it. A workflow is like a function, you have to **invoke** it:

```
workflow helloworld {

"Hello World"

}
helloworld
```